# Join Tables Relationships with SQL

Tags: php, mysql, php-5.3

I trying to create a facebook style news feed, where it display contents from your friend and yourself. At the moment I am really struggling, not sure if am doing it right.

I got a table called user_followers

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_Followers` (
  `user_follower_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `follower_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_followed` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_follower_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

and another one called usersActivity

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `usersActivity` (
  `activity_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `activity_identifier` enum('1','2','3') NOT NULL,
  `user_identifier` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `row_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`activity_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=24 ;
```

the user_id stores the id of the user, who friends with/following another user, and the follower_id is the id of person being followed

What am trying to do is get follower_id of all users that member 1 is following, then get their activities plus member 1 activity and display it on page. by checking if user_identifier is member 1 or people his/her is following.

so far this is wat i got:

```
// Fetch userActivity data
$activites = mysql_query("
  SELECT 
    a.activity_id, 
    a.row_id, 
    a.activity_identifier, 
    b.follower_id
  FROM usersActivity a INNER JOIN user_Followers b ON a.user_identifier = b.follower_id
  WHERE a.user_identifier=b.follower_id
  ORDER BY activity_id DESC 
  LIMIT 0,20");
```

I hope you can understand what i wrote above.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

in your sql query you have written 'user_Followes' instead of 'user_Followers'

Is that a typo in the sql query?

and also try aliasing your tables using AS

```
SELECT a.activity_id FROM usersActivity AS a
```